# add template for kendo tooltip in k-content attribute

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to add a kendo tooltip with some html template. In the example mentioned in the link:

```
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/angular
```

How would i have a template mentioned in `<script>` tag added as part of k-content? I have tooltip content bound from view model and the content is dynamic. The content has html tags as well.So how can i bind the template using html element attibutes only.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/8819854-tooltip-angular-content-template-directive

Comment: @user2439903 ho wdid you solve this , i am running into teh same issue

Comment: i used teamplateCache: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Answer (score -1):

You can use angular directive to create a template, then use it as k-content.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you explain that in a little more detail and maybe give a code example? I think that would help to better understand you answer.